# Placing integers into the next available position of an array inside of a for loop

Tags: php

Hi I am attempting to figure out how to iterate through integers, determine if they are prime and then put the primes in one array and the non primes into another.

I have already have the function finished for checking for primes which I will leave out for simplicity. I just can't seem to place the values into different arrays. Here is what I have so far.

Any insight on this is appreciated, I have searched through a lot of previous questions and can't seem to come up with a working answers yet, even though this seems so straight forward.

```
    <?php

              $start = 0;
              $end = 1000;
              $primes = array();
              $nonPrimes = array();


              for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++)
              {
                  if(isPrime($i))
                  {
                    //add to the next available position in $primes array;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  //add to the next available position in $nonPrimes array;
                  }
              }
?>
```

Comment: In order to learn it would be nice to know why I was down voted. If not I will assume some random person was just having a bad day =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) maybe?

```
if(isPrime($i))
{
    //add to the next available position in $primes array;
    array_push($primes,$i);
}
else
{
    //add to the next available position in $nonPrimes array;
    array_push($nonPrimes,$i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but please read the whole question. I already have the portion for finding the prime numbers I just need to fill in the commented section of my code and place the numbers into the next positions of my arrays.

Comment: @Biotic I changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate I knew it was simple.

Comment: If you can link me to a method of dumping the arrays into specific div classes that would be great. I would like to put the data from the arrays into div's with the classes .primes & .nonPrimes .

Comment: You can just put a `div` tag around the `if` tag and `else` tag right?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[]` operator to add an element to an array:

```
if (isPrime($i)) 
{
    $primes[] = $i;
}
else
{
    $nonPrimes[] = $i;
}
```

This will result in arrays like:

```
$primes[2, 3, 5, 7, 11];
```

and

```
$nonPrimes[1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10];
```

Comment: Thanks it is always good seeing multiple ways of doing things.